# WordPress Archive plugin

Tags: wordpress

I want to regularly take archived backup of my older posts. Could somebody suggest me a plugin which automatically archive the older post in a custom manner(May be weekly/Monthly/Yearly).

Answer (score 0):

1. download Recent Posts Plus plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/recent-posts-plus/
2. download Post Expirator plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-expirator/
   at the end of the posts useful life it is automatically re-categorised as 'old-posts' and this category is excluded from the plugin Recent Posts Plus
   Hope this can help